# $\lim_{(x,y)_\to(0,0)} \frac{x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$

Tags: calculus

This was a question on my calculus final:

$$\lim_{(x,y)_\to(0,0)} \frac{x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

I mistakenly found the limit to be 1/4. What would be the limit if it does exist?

Comment: Well if you approach the origin along the $x$-axis (so $y=0$ and $(x,y)=(x,0)$ and you take $x\to 0$), you should see that the limit is $0$. So from this, **if** the limit exists, then it is $0$. In general, if you can find two ways of approaching $(0,0)$ that yield different limits, then you can conclude that the limit does not exist.

Comment: The same argument is true for when you come down the $y$-axis. The function hits $0$ when one of $x$ or $y$ hits $0$, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

The limit $$\lim_{(x,y)_\to(0,0)} \frac{x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

does not exist.

Let $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$

Upon substitution we get $$\frac{x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = \frac {\sin(\theta)\cos^2 (\theta)}{r}$$
Note that for $\theta =0$ the fraction is identically zero while for $\theta = \pi/4$ the fraction tends to infinity.

Thus the limit does not exist.